# Is the current the same in each loop of a solenoid?

Tags: inductance

To find the magnetic field we find the field produced and then multiply with the number of turns, so it seems that current through all the turns is same i.e if 2 A current flows then in each loop the current would be 2 A. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.

The current being the same in each of the loops is viewed as a consequence of *conservation of charge.* In other words, charge doesn't disappear. Current is moving charge, so as long as charge isn't collecting/pooling up at any point in the wire, then the amount of charge per second flowing past one point must be the same as the amount of charge per second flowing past any other point in a single continuous wire. If it were different at some point, that would mean some charge was either collected somewhere or it disappeared.

Comment: Is biot Savort's law universal like coulomb's law, or law of gravitation

Comment: But isn't their the matter of self inductance and mutual inductance? Depending on the geometry of the solenoid, and where you look, the current could be a little different, like at the ends of the solenoid, right? In an ideal solenoid, the answer is yes. But in a real, physical solenoid, not necessarily so.